# Oop php front controller issue

Tags: php

I have a problem building a front controller for a project I have at school.
Here is the thing, i created several controllers per entities i.e. One to select, another one to delete etc... and this for posts and comments. So i have 6 controllers and then I'm being asked to build front controller above these controllers but i keep on adding layers (route all to index.php then from there I instantiate the front controller which then will send the request to the related controller with header(location:...) and it gets messy and very complicated because for some of the request i need to pass some ids in the url for the db request...
I can't use any framework so is there a cleaner way to build a front controller that can handle request with parameters in the url and some without?
Do i have to route everything to a single page (with htaccess i created a simple rule to send everything to index.php)?
And then from there again instantiate the front controller?
If you need some code I'll share this with you but it's a mess :)

Thanks guys, i need advise I'm kind of lost at this point

Comment: So basically your front controller is more of a router than a controller? Don't redirect, just instantiate and call other controller methods from the "front controller" if it is more of a router.

Comment: Yes indeed it's more of a router than a controller as such! But then i need to build classes for the other controllers e.g. Using a constructor? because there role is to instantiate methods from specific classes(method to select, insert, hydrate etc...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to build a basic router, what it does.

A router will parse the path and take parts of it and locate a controller file.  And then run a method in that file with arguments.  We will use this format for urls

```
  www.yoursite.com/index.php/{controller}/{method}/{args}
```

So for this example our url will be

```
  www.yoursite.com/index.php/home/index/hello/world
```

the `index.php` can be hidden using some basic .htaccess ( Mod Rewrite )

So lets define some things, first we will have folders

```
-public_html
  index.php
  --app
    ---controller
       home.php
```

So the main folder is `public_html` with the `index.php` and a folder named `app`.  Inside `app` is a folder named `controller` and inside that is our `home.php` contoller

Now for the Code ( yea )

index.php (basic router )

```
<?php
//GET URI segment from server, everything after index.php ( defaults to home )
$path_info = isset( $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] ) ? $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] : '/home';
//explode into an array - array_filter removes empty items such as this would cause  '/home//index/'  leading /, trailing / and // double slashes.
$args = array_filter( explode('/', $path_info) );

$controller_class = array_shift($args); //remove first item ( contoller )
$method = count( $args ) > 0 ? array_shift($args) : 'index'; //remove second item or default to index ( method )

$basepath = __DIR__.'/app/controller/'; //base path to controllers

if(!file_exists($basepath.$controller_class.".php") ){
    echo "SHOW 404";
    exit();
}

//instantiate controller class
require_once $basepath.$controller_class.".php";
$Controller = new $controller_class;

//check if method exists in controller
if(!method_exists( $Controller, $method ) ){
    echo "Method not found in controller / or 404";
    exit(); 
}

//call methods with any remaining args
call_user_func_array( [$Controller, $method], $args);
```

home.php ( controller )

```
<?php

class home{

    public function index( $arg1="", $arg2=""){
        echo "Arg1: ".$arg1 . "\n";
        echo "Arg2: ".$arg2 . "\n";
    }

    public function test( $arg1 = "" ){
        echo "Arg1: ".$arg1 . "\n";         
    }   
}
```

Now if you put in any of these urls

```
  www.yoursite.com/index.php
  www.yoursite.com/index.php/home
  www.yoursite.com/index.php/home/index
```

It should print ( defaults )

```
  Arg1: 
  Arg2:
```

If you do this url

```
  www.yoursite.com/index.php/home/index/hello/world
```

It should print

```
 Arg1: hello
 Arg2: world
```

And if you do this one

```
  www.yoursite.com/index.php/home/test/hello_world
```

it would print

```
  Arg1: hello_world
```

The last one, running in the second method `test` ( no echo arg2 ), this way you can see how we can add more controllers and methods with only having to code them into a controller.

This method still allows you to use the `$_GET` part of the url, as well as the URI part to pass info into the controller. So this is still valid

```
  www.yoursite.com/index.php/home/test/hello_world?a=1
```

and you could ( in home::test() ) output the contents of `$_GET` with no issues, this is useful for search forms etc.  Some pretty url methods prevent this which is just ... well ... crap.

In `.htaccess` with mod rewrite you would do this to remove index.php from the urls

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Then you can use urls without the index.php such as this

```
  www.yoursite.com/home/index/hello/world
```

This is the simplest Router I could come up with on such short notice, yes I just created it.  But this is a very similar ( although simplified ) implementation used in many MVC frameworks

PS. please understand how this is all done, so you actually learn something...

Many improvements could be made, such as allowing these urls

```
   www.yoursite.com/hello/world

   www.yoursite.com/home/hello/world

   www.yoursite.com/index/hello/world
```

Which would all fall back to the  a default of home controller and index method, but that would take some additional checks (for not found files and methods ) I cant be bothered with right now...

Comment: Sure, glad I could help.  Just learn from it, more the method and reasoning, then the code...

Comment: PS, a URL is a real path to a physical address, a URI is an imaginary path to a physical address ( at least that's how I define the 2 )

Comment: But thanks because it's hard to find good materials on that to be really honest

Comment: I've written a few of these over the years, and I am currently building an event driven framework ( slowly building it ... lol ) when I have time outside of work, https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/Evo

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple demo process (won't work, just an example).

**index.php**

```
//Say you called /index.php/do/some/stuff
$route = $_SERVER["PATH_INFO"]; //This will contain /do/some/stuff

$router = new Router();
$router->handle($route);
```

**router.php**

```
class Router {
     private static $routeTable = [
         "do/some/stuff" => [ "DoingSomeController" => "stuff" ]
     ];

     public function handle($route) {
          if (isset(self::$routeTable[trim($route,"/"])) {
              $controller = new self::$routeTable[trim($route,"/"][0];
              call_user_func([$controller,self::$routeTable[trim($route,"/"][1]]);

          }
     }
}
```

Basic demo, what some frameworks do.