# fix paths with pretty urls?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to use pretty links with my website, but i have a problem with paths of css and js files.

Thats what i wrote in .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^register register.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^login login.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^settings settings.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^logout logout.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^profile/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ profile.php?u=$1 [NC,L]
```

The problem here appears when i try to access profile.php with the variable 
example: http://example.com/xxxx/profile/ashraf 
This here will consider profile as the main folder when importing style files which is not a folder, it's just profile.php

Thank you

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you expect to happen? The path you gave `/xxxx/profile/ashraf` doesn't match any of your rules (in the last rule the path begins with `profile`, not `xxxx`).  Please show specifically the path to a CSS that you're trying to access, and any error that you get.

Comment: xxxx is the main path  and profile is a php file, 
i am not working on the root file i am working in sub folder which is xxx and the htaccess file is inside it

Comment: styles path is xxxx/style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can add this before your rules

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Basically what this ( common on many CMS systems ) says, is if Not a real file `!-f`, or a real directory `!-d`  then continue on.  Therefore if the file actually exists, such as a css file, it will not pass the condition and will not be re-written.

So I would say put it right here

```
RewriteEngine on
## insert here ##
RewriteRule ^register register.php [NC,L]
```

You may have to place it before each rule, that I am not that sure of, as I haven't done a whole lot with `.htaccess` in like 5 years.  Basically when I learned how to use the `URI` instead of a `URL` and route everything through a index.php and a router script.

This is the extent of my `.htaccess` files these days ( just FYI for my explanation of my lack of remembering ) and it literally never changes.  That's one of the biggest benefits of building a router and using the `URI`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

This answer I did has a pretty good ( if I say so ) explanation of how what I call the `URI` method works.

[How to change the name of the directory in url in php using htaccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45362337/how-to-change-the-name-of-the-directory-in-url-in-php-using-htaccess/45362526#45362526)

Here is another answer I did on this topic that outlines how to build a basic router

[Oop php front controller issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44841203/oop-php-front-controller-issue/44842136#44842136)

Anyway hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The browser cannot know if the paths in the URL are real directories or just parts used in rewrite rules.  When it sends a request to the web server to get the CSS, the browser must convert it any relative urls to absolute and assumes the current page is in a path of directories.

In other words, in your HTML page, always use absolute urls: `<link href="/xxxx/style/mycss.css" ...>`

Comment: thank you, but can i even make the link dynamic, meaning it work anywhere without having to edit the style path

Comment: This is not true It can know.

Answer (score 0):

Put this after the profile.php rule. This will take out the extra 'profile'.

```
RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)$ $1 [L]
```

Or use a long path to the css file:

```
<link href="/xxxx/style/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Either one should work.